# Do not use Illuminate in Laravel packages, Laravel manual modules

Tags: php, laravel-4

When creating a package in Laravel, the packages use "\Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider" in their *ServiceProvider.php. Which is located in the **package** \vendor directory.

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->package('faiawuks/articles');
    include __DIR__.'/../../../routes.php';
}
```

As you see I need Illuminate: $this->package to register my package specific routes.

I've noticed that Illuminate also exists inside the **main** vendor directory. Is it possible to remove the Illuminate vendor package for my created workbench package and use the main vendor\Illuminate package? I'ts going to be a private workbench package anyway?

I want to create 5+ packages for my application, so I can split it into 'modules'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it for now by creating my own directory structure in the directory ./modules and using this in composer.json:

```
"psr-0": {
    "Articles": "modules/"
}
```

inside the *"autoload": {* part. So my structure is as following:

```
mylaravelproject
    - modules
        - Articles
        - *othermodules
```

The PSR-0 autoloader looks for classes inside ./modules/Articles. The namespace to use in the Articles directory is:

```
namespace Articles;
```